# Performance issue when querying items inside circles

Tags: mongodb

I need to query 300 items among 100,000+ and all of these 300 must be contained inside a set of many circles (hundreds). I am using a MongoDB database and here is a part of my logs:

```
"command": "{
  count: \"items\",
  query: {
    location.coordinates: {
      $geoWithin: {
        $box: [
          [ 2.172203063964844, 48.78040136289702 ],
          [ 2.506599426269531, 48.98765230234855 ]
        ]
      }
    },
  search: \"rent\", isPublished: true,
  $or: [{
    location.coordinates: {
      $geoWithin: {
        $center: [
          [ 2.512155566998092, 48.96309599735446 ], 0.002204591143019205 ]
        }
      }
    },{
      location.coordinates: {
        $geoWithin: {
          $center: [
            [ 2.316596761508817, 48.88132429394468 ], 0.02168492811759336
          ]
        }
      }
    }, { location.coord...",
```

I tried to add a geospatial index but the performances are still very bad (around 10 seconds).

I'm building my query with mongoose:

```
    query.where({
      $or: arrayOfNodes
    });
```

where a node looks like:

```
{
    'location.coordinates': 
    {
        $geoWithin: 
        { 
            $center: [ [parseFloat(node.lng), parseFloat(node.lat)],
            reachableRadiusInDegrees] 
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have and idea how I could improve this query?

Comment: Could you please provide the query? This looks pretty strange. As far as I can tell from that, you are doing two individual geolocation searches, is that correct?

Comment: I'm building my query with mongoose:

        query.where({
          $or: arrayOfNodes
        });

where a node looks like:
{
            'location.coordinates': {
              $geoWithin: { $center: [ [parseFloat(node.lng), parseFloat(node.lat)], reachableRadiusInDegrees] }
            }
}

Comment: I need much more information. What are you trying to accomplish? Why do the different coordinates have different radiuses attached? Please describe the use case as clearly as possible.